# Mapping EXCEL Sheet to Database using JPA Hibernate

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, jpa

I would like to map an simple excel table to my javaEE application using hibernate. I'm really new to Databases and ORM so i would like to know if the following relations make sense and in how many Entities would make sense to split the Table.

This is the attributes contained in the Excel spreadsheet:

`(Office Room Number|ComputerName|ComputerIP|Computer OS|UserFirstName|UserLastName)`

Relations:

- `OfficeRoomNumber -- 1 : N -- Users`

  - N users working in 1 Office?
- `OfficeRoomNumber -- 1 : N -- Computer`

  - N Computers are in 1 Office ?
- `User -- 1:1 -- Computer`

  - 1 User got 1 Computer?

Thanks for any help and sorry for my horrible English.

Comment: Could you provide some example input and output?

Comment: i want to create an simple CRUD application with this table an normal row would look like this (12 | Computer-1012 | 10.0.10.51 | Win 10 | Peter | Miller)  thx for your help

Comment: Your question does not demonstrate what you really want. You need to model OO classes as entitys. Another thing is how to transform the data of an excel sheet into these modeled objects.

Tell if you have doubts about model entitys. About excel, use Apache POI library to read sheets and converting into objects.

Comment: Yeah im not sure how to model the Entitys and use the Annotations. My idea was to have 3 Entitys (OfficeRoom, Computer and User)  and use the Annotations like i described the Relations with "@ManyToOne" and "@OneToOne"

Comment: @Tabax first forgot about JPA and model your entitys in OO. After that. read this topic https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-entity

Comment: @HenriqueFernandesCipriano I think you got the question wrong, as this is not about processing xls sheets, e.g. with Apache POI. Tabax just wanted to know how to map this kind of domain with JPA annotations. Please see my answer which helped him a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my 50c for modelling your domain. First, one can use an abstract base class for generic aspects, such as primary key generation:

```
@MappedSuperClass
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "pk-sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "pk-sequence", sequenceName = "ID_GEN", allocationSize = 1)
    protected Long objectID = -1;

    @Version
    private int version;

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public long getObjectID() {
        return objectID;
    }   
}
```

*Note well, this can be enhanced to include other generic aspects, e.g. creation/modification date/timestamps.*

Next, we introduce three domain classes/entities as follows:

```
@Entity
public class OfficeRoom extends AbstractEntity {

    private String name;
    private String roomNumer;

    @ManyToMany // Maybe an employee is associated with 2 or more office places she/he might work at?
    private Collection<Employee> staff;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="location")
    private Collection<Computer> equipment;

    // getters and setters
}
```

I added a comment as you can see above on the field staff. Potentially, one would like to associated two different office rooms to certain VIP staff, so you should consider this case in modelling your domain by using `@ManyToMany` here already.

Moving on with:

```
@Entity
public class Computer extends AbstractEntity {
    private String name;
    private String model;
    private String vendor;
    private String installedOS;
    private String ipAddress;

    @ManyToOne
    private OfficeRoom location;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="machine") // Maybe a computer is associated with 2 or more employees?
    private Collection<Employee> user;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Again, consider my comment carefully. Finally,...

```
@Entity
public class Employee extends AbstractEntity {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    // other staff related attributes here ...

    @ManyToOne
    private Computer machine;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Note well: Use only annotations originating from the `javax.persistence` package, in your import statements to stay compliant with the JPA 2.x specification and remain JPA-provider neutral with your application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! you really helped me here! i know what to do now :)

Comment: @Tabax If the answer helped you and you learned from it in the long run, please consider granting an upvote as well.